# Why is my Django view decorator not getting the request passed to it?

Tags: python, django, decorator

I have a setup looking something like this:

```
def foo_decorator(function):
    @wraps(function)
    def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
        print kwargs
        return function(*args, **kwargs)

    return decorator

@foo_decorator
def analytics(request, page_id, promotion_id):
    pass
```

Outputting:

```
{'promotion_id': u'11','page_id': u'119766481432558'}
```

Why is my decorator not getting `request` passed to it?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`request` isn't a keyword argument to the view, it's the first positional argument. You can access it as `args[0]`.

```
def foo_decorator(function):
    @wraps(function)
    def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
        print args[0]
        return function(*args, **kwargs)

    return decorator
```

I would recommend that you change the function signature to include `request` explicitly:

```
def foo_decorator(function):
    @wraps(function)
    def decorator(request, *args, **kwargs):
        print request
        return function(request, *args, **kwargs)

    return decorator
```

Comment: I think you are missing ** in front of kwargs when calling the 'function'

Comment: Thanks Patrik, fixed now.

Answer (score 6):

The request is not passed as a keyword argument. It's in `args`, not `kwargs`.

Comment: Hah, I just realized this after spending a good hour confused. The light bulb finally went up that `args` can contain things that's not in `kwargs`! How dumb of me. Thanks!